# ASP.NET WebAPI. Do not persist sessions

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET 6 WebAPI application.
I've implemented login functionality, which boils down to calling:

```
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, claimsPrincipal);
```

It sets a cookie with key `.AspNetCore.Cookies` and value of ID of the user session.

Somehow these sessions are persisted across WebAPI restarts. User agent with this cookie is still logged in when sending HTTP requests to WebAPI after restart. Where these sessions are persisted? Is there a way to disable this behaviour?

For clarity: I'm not using `.AspNetCore.Session`-related functionality, we're speaking solely on `.AspNetCore.Cookies` based user authentication.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There should be session storage configured somewhere, you should check your configuration.

Comment: How is your Program.cs like?

Comment: I have `builder.Services.AddSession(options =>{});` configured in `Program.cs`. Investigating this further.

Comment: I've tried to remove `builder.Services.AddSession(...)` and `app.UseSession();` with no result - sessions are still persisted somewhere.

Comment: Here is my [`Program.cs`](https://gist.github.com/yaromir/0a4b6709eb90fb520b94279bb83054be).